# How to get the profile from an event in atg?

Tags: atg

I am using nameContextElementPreUnbound( NameContextBindingEvent pEvent) method to be triggered just before the session expires so that we can save the session details before it expires.

My method is getting triggered after I set the session-timeout but I am unable to fetch the Profile from an Event. I tried using NucleusNameResolver to fetch atg.userprofiling.Profile component but it gets a null profile everytime. Probably it fetches me a new profile component and not the profile from which I have logged in.

Please suggest some way to get the profile from an event (NameContextBindingEvent).

Answer (score 0):

ATG has a built in component for [backing up the session](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Platform.10-2/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s2301sessionsaverservlet01.html) however assuming that you truly want the [session expiry event](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Platform.10-2/ATGPersProgGuide/html/s1202eventtriggers01.html), again this event is already built in and can be enabled by configuration. When this event triggers a DMS message is sent which contains a reference to the user profile.

To customize you would need to do something along the lines of:

1. Ensure that the `SessionEventTriggers` are enabled on `/atg/dynamo/servlet/dafpipeline/SessionEventTrigger` component.
2. Create a message sink which listens for the `EndSession` event.
3. Create  message handler which does whatever you need it do.

Remember that the user profile could also be transient i.e. the user is not actually logged in so you might need logic to deal with this.  Also remember that a lot of the sessions can be non-users e.g. robots like Googlebot so be careful when saving sessions.

.